# Long tap instead of simple when simulating

Tags: java, android

In my app, I need to simulate tap event. Im using this code:

```
View mLayout = findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
float width = mLayout.getWidth() / 2.0f;
float height = mLayout.getHeight() / 2.0f;
view.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), 0, width, height, 0));
view.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), 1, width, height, 0));
```

LogCat says, that there is less than 10ms interval between up and down events, but view thinks, that long tap performed (experimentally i found, that it requires nearly 300ms delay between events). 
onTouchEvent instead of dispatchTouchEvent works same.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Use Thread.sleep(300) between your events

Comment: Maybe my question was unclear, but im trying to do single tap, getting long instead)